# Review Queue - Alert

Tags: discussion, design

I don't see any alert or notification when there are items in the Queue, in StackOverflow we see [image]

However, on StackExchange, nothing is displayed, or maybe I am colorblind and did not know about it.

Are there changes still pending?

Comment: That's an icon that are review queue has more than some number of items in it, and requires more users to review those items. I don't believe any of the child sites have this feature enabled, and even if they did, very rarely are the quenes on this site close to being full.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red

Comment: doesn't seem to work all the time, for example, yesterday i noticed the red dot when there were pending actions, however, today, none.

Comment: Looks like they are enabled on child sites, with site specific values per queue. Between caching, other people reviewing, people self deleting their posts, there's going to be some inaccuracy in the numbers. Try looking through that meta post, it might help provide some info.

Comment: I see that alert now on the Edit review queue but not the others.